# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'userwithnopassword' @'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am setting up new symfony 5 project. I am not able to run migrations because of following error.

```
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] 
[1045] Access denied for user 'userwithnopassword'  
  @'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

In my .env file I have following configuration:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://userwithnopassword@127.0.0.1:3306/my_db?serverVersion=5.7
```

I took following steps to create the database and attach the user to it

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# create database my_db;
postgres=# create user userwithnopassword;
postgres=# grant all privileges on database my_db to userwithnopassword;
```

when I run \l in psql I get the following:

```
         Name          |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |        Access privileges        
------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------------
 my_db    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                   +
                        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres          +
                        |          |          |             |             | userwithnopassword=CTc/postgres
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not *hugely* familiar with Postgres... but `SQLSTATE[HY000] 
[1045]` looks like a MySQL/MariaDB error code - and that entire DSN string looks like you're connecting to  MySQL/MariaDB server (`mysql://userwithnopassword@127.0.0.1:3306/my_db?serverVersion=5.7`) ... have you got both Postgres and MariaDB installed and you're connecting to the wrong database server?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add the two points "**:**" after the db username to keep the format even if there is no password:

**DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password:@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name**

so :

DATABASE_URL=mysql://userwithnopassword:@127.0.0.1:3306/my_db